# How to use CodeMirror to apply some styles to a special marks in the editor

Tags: codemirror

Here is my scenario: I have an input textarea where the user introduces some text. The text is plain text but the user can use some defined macros, such as {{username}}.

Here is an example

```
<textarea>The user {{Username}} loggedin at {{now}}</textarea>
```

I don't want that the user has to know the syntax, so I will have some buttons, which when clicked insert the macro automatically in textarea.  I want to apply some basic style to this macros. For example, the content above should be transformed in

```
The user <span class="cm-mystyle">Username</span> logged in at <span class="cm-mystyle">Now</span>
```

When using the editor the user should handle the 'span' as a block, which means that the user cannot change the content of the span (just delete).

I don't know if CodeMirror is the right tool to handle this scenario.

After reading the documentation, my first approach was to define a mode, to handle my tokens {{Username}}. But it seems that I can only return the style to be applied to the token. So I can have this

```
The user <span class="cm-mystyle">{{Username}}</span> logged in...
```

But I want to remove the {{}} chars. Then I read about the widgets, which seems to me that can be used to handle my scenario.

To be honest, I am a litle bit confused how to approach my problem. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `markText` method is probably what you want. Find the macro text, and mark it with the `replacedBy` option set to some styled `span` that contains only the text you want to display.

http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText